# SuiteCRM, sugarCRM : Modifying the name of subpanels

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Modifying the name of subpanels using studio works perfectly, 
but when i do quick repair and rebuild or when i clear simply the cache, i lose the modifications.

Thank you for your help !

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it happens Many time , Just try to do using through code,

you can change the subpanel name in `Custom/Extension/Modules/YOUrmodule/language` 
Just find your label and change it.
OR please check you gave proper permissions to your folder.